Error when using CDI Decorator to decorate the managed Validator
I have a stateless Java EE 7 WebService and want to use the validation framework to validate the incoming data. This all works fine. I then want to transform any ConstraintViolationException to something more friendly for the client and thought a decorator would be ideal for this.
Something like the below. However when I deploy that, the ValidationInterceptor complains that it cannot find a Validator implementation. Which kind of makes sense to me. I have been able to get the functionality working by means of an interceptor which fires before the validation interceptor and which can catch the exception however the decorator approach seems a bit cleaner.
Is there something I am missing here? My background is mostly Spring so not too familiar with CDI.
Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Validator with qualifiers @Default
      at injection point [UnbackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private org.hibernate.validator.cdi.internal.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor.validator
      at org.hibernate.validator.cdi.internal.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor.validator(ValidationInterceptor.java:0)
    WELD-001475: The following beans match by type, but none have matching qualifiers:
      - ValidatorBean [id=org.hibernate.validator.cdi.internal.ValidatorBean_hv]
     -- WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Validator with qualifiers @Default
      at injection point [UnbackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private org.hibernate.validator.cdi.internal.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor.validator
      at org.hibernate.validator.cdi.internal.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor.validator(ValidationInterceptor.java:0)
    WELD-001475: The following beans match by type, but none have matching qualifiers:
      - ValidatorBean [id=org.hibernate.validator.cdi.internal.ValidatorBean_hv]
    ]]

@Decorator
public abstract class ValidationDecorator implements Validator {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ValidationDecorator.class.getName());
    
    //the predefine validator bean created by the container
    @Inject
    @Delegate
    private Validator validator;

    @Override
    public <T> Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> validate(T object, Class<?>... groups) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, () -> String.format("Validation decorator validating %s", object));

        Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> violations = null;

        try {
            violations = validator.validate(object, groups);
        } catch (ConstraintViolationException ex) {
            try {
                // build a client friendly message
                SOAPFactory factory = SOAPFactory.newInstance();
                SOAPFault fault = factory.createFault("A validation error occurred", new QName("ValidationError"));

                throw new SOAPFaultException(fault);
            } catch (SOAPException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return violations;
    }
}


You need to use @Any qualifier on the injectable field - see Decorator delegate injection points section of the CDI specification.
// ...
@Inject
@Delegate
@Any
private Validator validator;
// ...

